# creating an array of NSObject classes

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, nsarray

I have a `NSObject` class in which I am sending a `NSDictionary` object too, the class object then sets all the entries in the `NSDictionary` to their native types that are variables in the `NSObject` class.

I would then like to pass this `NSObject` class into its own `NSMutableArray` however my app is crashing when this happens.

below is the code calling the `NSObject` Class and then trying to set it into a `NSMutableArray`.

```
NSArray *filteredArray = parsedDataArrayOfDictionaries; //dictionary entries are currently in nsstring format
SearchResultList *searchResultList = [[SearchResultList alloc]init];
NSMutableArray *testArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

int myCount = 0;

while (myCount <= [filteredArray count]) {
    //call class and pass current NSDictionary in array[myCount]
    [searchResultList assignSearchData:filteredArray[myCount]];
    searchResultList = (SearchResultList*)[testingDic objectForKey:@"myObject"];
    testArray[myCount] = searchResultList; //create array of nsobjectclassed, this is also where the app fails
    NSLog(@"%@", testArray[myCount]);
}
```

Hopefully this is making some sense, I am getting abit lost in the middle of the while statements... I know I need to get back the `NSObject` Class then assign it to an array.. but im just not sure how to do this, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense.  Where does seriesSearchResultList come from??  Why do you create a SearchResultList object and assign it to searchResultList, then later overwrite that pointer (and leak the object)?  What is supposedly in testingDic?

Comment: opps. seriesSearchresultList is ment to be searcResultList.. dunno what happened their. the answer to the second part of your question is: I have gotten abit lost.. I thought i was receiving the NSObject class into searchResultList then putting that object into the array.. thats what I thought was happening.. but i guess its not.. Im just abit lost.. I am trying to find a equivalent example to what I am doing but I cannot find one.

Comment: I'd suggest you learn how to program with Java first.  Learning programming with Objective-C is a very bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are exceeding the size of the array `filteredArray`

```
while (myCount <= [filteredArray count]) {
```

should read

```
while (myCount <[filteredArray count]) {
```

as the count of an array is one higher than the last object's index, as the indices starts at 0.

honestly I am not sure, what you are trying to achieve, but you should consider to use [fast enumeration](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocFastEnumeration.html) instead of the while statement

```
for (id obj in filteredArray) {
```

or even fancier [block-based enumeration](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html)

```
NSMutableArray *testArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[filteredArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    //...
    [testArray addObject:obj];
}];
```

Comment: Okay, thanks for the response I am going to read fast enumeration now. What I am trying to achieve is taking a NSMutableArray full of NSDictionary thats entries are all strings and pass them to a NSObject class that takes each entry in the dictionary and converts the NSString to their true types, and do that for each NSDictionary Object in the MutableArray and then pass each NSObject Class thats beeing created and values set into their own NSMutable array that can then be used for sorting different entries in the class. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: This actually worked.. however I have to change the method return type that I was calling from searchResultList to return self. then I also took away the `[count]` after `testArray addobject:obj];` This seemed to get things going which was a good relief.. however I still have to do some testing. to make sure there are no random errors popping up. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score -1):

Try using `NSMutableArray` addObject.  There is no 'C' style [] operator for `NSMutableArray`.

Comment: Not true with Modern Objective-C and the LLVM4 compiler in Xcode 4.4 upwards. Object literals and subscripting are supported

Comment: hrmmm this is causing this problem **erminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'**

Comment: @Abizem - Thanks for letting me know about that.  It will save quite a bit of typing.

Comment: @HurkNburkS Make sure you do not access elements that are outside the range.  If you only add one item but try to access objectAtIndex:2 then you'll get an exception.

Comment: with one added item it will also lead to an access error with index 1.

Comment: I was trying to make it abundantly clear that it was outside the range.  I should have said "1 or greater".  Thanks

Comment: right, so what I need to do is add the several objects before I try to access any of them..

Comment: Only access items in the range.  This is an array and not a dictionary.  If there are 5 items then the only indexes that will work are 0,1,2,3 and 4.

Comment: I think you still need to use addObject to add items to testArray.  Subscripting does not automatically add items for you.

Comment: yes I have changed to addObject `[test[myCount] addObject:seriesSearchResultList];` however I am still receiving errors. I am not sure why this is happening. **Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '-[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'**

Comment: Try `[testArray addObject:seriesSearchResultList]`.

Comment: this is what ended up working however in the method being called from the NSObject class I had to `return self`